# Альтернатива FindWindow на Маке

Tags: c++, winapi, macos, mac

Есть какая-то альтернатива FindWindow (функция, которая возвращает указатель на окно по его title) из WinAPI у Мака? Пытаюсь прикинуть сложность переноса пары методов на Мак, но никогда с ним не работал и легкий гугл показал, что там какая-то ерунда (как и вся ОС, в общем-то) с этим. 
Сабж - реально ли получить окно\указатель на него\сразу скриншот окна на Маке из С++?

Comment: Используете Cocoa?

Comment: @Unick, Вообще я в C++ Qt и плохо знаком с технологиями Мака. Но я так понимаю, единственный выход прикрутить ко всему этому ObjC и Cocoa?

Comment: Ооо ObjC, я месяц привыкал к синтаксису :(